# Sample data for an ADC

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-idle

I applied the following code (https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/ads1x15/en/latest/examples.html) to read voltage.

In the last line of python code, I have set time.sleep command as (1/3300 s)

I have following queries:

1. In the time column, time-step comes out to be approximately (0.02 s). However expected time-step is (1/3300)s. Why does this occur?
2. How do I ensure that the time-step i.e sampling frequency between two successive time data points remains **exactly at 3300 Hz.**  ?
3. How do I ensure that 1st time-data point starts with "0"?

Can somebody please clarify my doubts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampling rate of the ADS1015 is meant to be 3300S/sec only in continuous mode, and sampling one channel at a time.
There are 2 steps here:

1. Ensure your ADC is in continuous sampling mode.
   Putting it in continuous mode would be something like "adc.mode = 0", provided your library supports it. I have used this one https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15 and it does support it.
2. Ensure that the Data rate in the config register is set to 3300. (page 16 on the datasheet at https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ads1015.pdf)

Purely that would also mostly not be enough, getting to the full potential of the ADC would also need a compatible processor that can handle large amounts of data on its i2c bus. Something like a raspberry pi is mostly not powerful enough.
Using faster languages like C/C++ would also help.

Comment: The raspberry pi is also not quick enough to support a time.sleep of 1/3300. The time.sleep library is only accurate to a few miliseconds. 
From personal experience the best you can get from a Raspberry Pi is about 250 samples/sec. ( no loop delay and a very efficient code)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aditya for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 problems and need to read the time module docs.

1. time.time is not guaranteed to be accurate to more than a second.  In the following, in IDLE Shell on Win 10, multiple time.time() calls give same time.

```
>>> for i in range(30):
        print(time.perf_counter(), time.time(), time.perf_counter())

8572.4002846 1607086901.7035756 8572.4002855
8572.4653746 1607086901.756807 8572.4653754
8572.4706208 1607086901.7724454 8572.4706212
8572.4755909 1607086901.7724454 8572.4755914
8572.4806756 1607086901.7724454 8572.4806759
... # time.time continues repeating 3 or 4 times.
```

2. time.sleep(t) has a minimum system-dependent interval, even if t is much smaller.  On Windows, it is about .015 seconds.  There is no particular upper limit if there is other system activity.

```
>>> for i in range(5):
        print(time.perf_counter())
        time.sleep(.0000001)

9125.1041623
9125.1188101
9125.134417
9125.1565579
9125.1722012
```

3. Printing to IDLE's shell is slower than running a program direct with Python (from command line) and printing to the system console.  For one thing, IDLE runs user code in a separate process, adding interprocess overhead.  For another, IDLE is a GUI program and the GUI framework, tk via tkinter, add more overhead.  IDLE is designed for learning Python and developing Python programs. It is not optimized for running Python programs.

If user code outputs to a tkinter GUI it creates in the same process, avoiding the interprocess delay, the minimum interval is much shorter, about .0012 seconds in this particular example.

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> r = tk.Tk()
>>> t = tk.Text(r)
>>> t.pack()
>>> for i in range(5):
    t.insert('insert', f'{time.perf_counter()}\n')
    r.update()

# In the text widget...
9873.6484271
9873.6518752
9873.6523338
9873.6527421
9873.6532307
```